# Fast way of refreshing complex plots with ipywidgets

Tags: ipywidgets

I have made a widget that uses a plot function that plots a pandas bar plot and two images. This takes a few seconds to plot, but worse than that, the plot disappears for a few seconds before the new one appears.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive
from IPython.display import display


class DummyPlotter:

  def plot(self, random_state):
    plt.figure(figsize=[30,10])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(size=200), columns=['prob'])
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    df.plot.bar( y='prob', ax=ax);
    # Plot Image
    ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 4, 5);
    ax1.imshow(np.random.uniform(size=[300,300]));

    # Plot Explainability Figure
    ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 4, 6);
    ax2.imshow(np.random.uniform(size=[300,300]));


dp = DummyPlotter()
w = interactive(dp.plot, random_state=10)
display(w)
```

How can I prevent the plot from disappearing before being updated?
How can I make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly you do a `df.plot.bar()` twice, which seems a bit redundant, could you remove it?

2) I did a lineprofile of your example code, the pandas bar plot takes the longest so start there to make the function quicker:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    10                                             def plot(self, random_state):
    11         1       1834.0   1834.0      0.2      plt.figure(figsize=[30,10])
    12         1       2573.0   2573.0      0.2      df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(size=200), columns=['prob'])
    13         1      67474.0  67474.0      5.7      ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    14         1     997202.0 997202.0     83.5      df.plot.bar( y='prob', ax=ax);
    15                                           #     df.plot.bar()
    16                                               # Plot Image
    17         1      69439.0  69439.0      5.8      ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 4, 5);
    18         1       5004.0   5004.0      0.4      ax1.imshow(np.random.uniform(size=[300,300]));
    19                                           
    20                                               # Plot Explainability Figure
    21         1      46301.0  46301.0      3.9      ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 4, 6);
    22         1       3886.0   3886.0      0.3      ax2.imshow(np.random.uniform(size=[300,300]));
```

[See here for description](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.07-timing-and-profiling.html#Line-By-Line-Profiling-with-%25lprun)

3) On your second question, using ipywidgets interactive, the output window will clear as soon as a new image is displayed. Your bar plot appears first, so this causes the old output to be cleared, and then you have to wait for the next two plots to be displayed.

4) You can also do `w = interactive(dp.plot, random_state=10, continuous_update=False)` so that the plot happens only when you let go of the slider in a particular position, rather than every value you move the slider through.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response and suggestions. Unfortunately, this does not seem to resolve the problem of plots disappearing and a long delay before the updated plot appears. This also seems to be  even worse in Jupiter lab compared to notebooks?

Comment: Can you line profile your function to give some timings?

If you want more control over when the output is cleared and objects are displayed, you can use an `ipwidgets.Output()` widget, rather than using `interactive`.

Comment: The one function that calculates the output of one of the subplots takes 90% of the time. But even if this is removed, the plot still vanishes before the refresh is plotted and this is very annoying. I will check out 'ipwidgets.Output()', thanks. Any pointers on how this can be used to solve the plot disappearing issue?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to your issue, but in case it helps someone else:

I've found when using ipywidgets that including any sort of printing/logging in the functions which are doing the plotting can cause the "redrawing" to be much slower and less elegant.

For example, the below code, run in a Jupyter notebook:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    
@interact(value=widgets.FloatSlider(1, min=0.1, max=5, continuous_update=False))
def plot_data(value):
    xs = np.linspace(0, 100, 10001)
    ys = np.cos(xs + value) * value

    print('Plotting')  # or a log message

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
    fig.set_size_inches(18, 6)
    ax[0].plot(xs, ys)
    ax[1].scatter(xs, ys)
```

With the `print` statement included, the redraw is slow, and the whole figure/plot visibly disappears and then reappears whenever the slider is moved. This makes it very hard to see the effect of moving the slider. A log message seems to have the same effect.

However, when the `print` statement is removed, the redraw is quicker and *the figure stays in place* - it's only the series within the axes that are redrawn. This makes it much easier to view the changes in the chart as the slider moves.